# How do I integrate this function? I've tried every method I can think of, help!

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the value of the integral $\int_{40}^{64} y^2(100y-4000)^{1/2} dy$

Comment: Try the substitution $u = 100y - 4000.$ This will allow the binomial aspect to be transferred from the square root (which can't be rewritten in a useful way) to the square term (which can be expanded).

Comment: I think that you've missed the purpose of this website... That's a pretty technical problem and there are even online calculators for such integrals - try this one: https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: @Tair Galili: The problem is fine for this website, but the OP should have provided some partial attempts and what went wrong. However, there are many, many very similar such integration problems already here. In fact, I think I gave a answer that discusses this general "trick" with several examples, but I don't feel up to trying to search for it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. Substitute $u = 100y - 4000$.
$$du = 100 dy$$
$$dy = du/100$$
(I didn't want to change the bounds because big number look bad).
Also, we can say $y^{2} = ((u+4000)/100)^{2}$.
Now, your new integral:
$$1/100\int ((u+4000)/100)^{2}\sqrt(u) du$$
Now, can you integrate this and sub u back and then definitely integrate from 40 to 64?

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2(100y-4000)^{1/2}dy=10y^2(y-40)^{1/2}dy$$
now you could try letting $u=y-40,du=dy$ so:
$$10(u+40)^2u^{1/2}du=10u^{1/2}(u^2+80u+40^2)$$
so your integral becomes:
$$10\int_0^{24}\left(u^{5/2}+80u^{3/2}+40^2u^{1/2}\right)du$$
now this should be easier